# Android db error's

Tags: android, sqlite

I created an app to connect to an existing sqlite db, and display some basic information from the db.. but it's closing unexpectedly in my emulator and I'm not sure what the errors mean. The db only has two tables, Information and android_metadata.

The only error I'm getting in the project files is in AndroidManifest.xml. It says: "Attribute minSdkVersion (8) is lower than the project target API level (10)" Other SO posts say that this can be ignored, so I haven't edited it (and it doesn't seem like it's the problem in the logcat trace.)

This is the activity that populates the listview with the 'states' colunn in the db:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import healthy.com.sdp.R;
import healthy.com.sdp.db.DataBaseHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StateListActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView _listView;
    private List<StateDisease> stateNames = new ArrayList<StateDisease>();
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder ;
    AlertDialog alert;
    Context _context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.state_list);        

        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        _listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listState);
        _listView.setAdapter(new SingleTextAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.adapter_single_text, stateNames));

        _listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
        _context = this;
        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.executeRawQuery("Select * from Information");


            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
                {
                    StateDisease sd = new StateDisease();
                    sd._stateId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    sd._percentHeartDisease = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("HeartDisease"));
                    sd._percentObesity = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Obesity"));                    
                    sd._stateName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("States"));                  
                    sd._percentLungDisease = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("LungDisease"));

                    stateNames.add(sd);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }


            myDbHelper.close();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener clickListener = new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                long id) {      

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DiseaseSelectionActivity.class); 
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(Constant.STATE_ID, stateNames.get(pos)._stateId);
            b.putString(Constant.STATE_NAME, stateNames.get(pos)._stateName);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };
}
```

And this is the logcat trace:

```
03-11 07:14:33.013: I/Database(336): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Information
03-11 07:14:33.013: W/System.err(336): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Information: , while compiling: Select * from Information
03-11 07:14:33.022: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-11 07:14:33.022: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
03-11 07:14:33.022: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
03-11 07:14:33.022: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
03-11 07:14:33.022: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at healthy.com.sdp.db.DataBaseHelper.executeRawQuery(DataBaseHelper.java:149)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at healthy.com.sdp.activity.StateListActivity.onCreate(StateListActivity.java:58)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 07:14:33.032: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 07:14:33.050: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 07:14:33.050: W/System.err(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/System.err(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 07:14:33.052: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
03-11 07:14:33.052: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{healthy.com.sdp/healthy.com.sdp.activity.StateListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at healthy.com.sdp.activity.StateListActivity.onCreate(StateListActivity.java:61)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-11 07:14:33.072: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
03-11 07:14:37.442: I/Process(336): Sending signal. PID: 336 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing statement/query

```
    Select * from Information
```

While this table "Information" is not have been created before.
see this [link/tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to know how to use sqlite db in better way